# Dismiss notification on click

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, notifications

I am using Flutter Local Notification to trigger periodic notifications in my app.

It provides a callback, which is executed when user taps on the notification,

I want to use the callback to run a async function, but i don't want to launch the app when the user clicks on it. I simply want to dismiss the notification.

Is there any way to achieve it?

Here is my code.

```
    var initializationSettingsAndroid =
        AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
    var initializationSettingsIOS = IOSInitializationSettings();
    var initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
        initializationSettingsAndroid, initializationSettingsIOS);
    _notificationPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
    _notificationPlugin.initialize(
      initializationSettings,
      onSelectNotification: onSelectNotification,
    );
```

My callback function,

```
  Future onSelectNotification(String payload) async {
 showDialog(
 context: context,
builder: (_) => AlertDialog(
    title: Text("Hello"),
   content: Text("content"),
  ),
);

   AnAsyncFunction();
  }
```

Notification triggering function,

```
Future getPeriodicNoification() async {
     print("hello");
// // Show a notification every minute with the first appearance happening a minute after invoking the method
     var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
       'your channel id',
      'your channel name',
      'your channel description',      
importance: Importance.Max,
      priority: Priority.High,
    );
    var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics = IOSNotificationDetails();
   var platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
         androidPlatformChannelSpecifics, iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics);
 await _notificationPlugin.periodicallyShow(0, 'repeating title',
    'repeating body', RepeatInterval.EveryMinute, );
  }
```